# How to access protected data in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli, woocommerce

I am using this to get the data from the latest completed order:

```
<?php
function get_last_order_id(){
    global $wpdb;
    $statuses = "wc-completed";

    // Getting last Order ID (max value)
    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT MAX(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
        WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND post_status IN ('$statuses')
    " );
    return reset($results);
}
$latest_order_id = get_last_order_id(); // Last order ID
echo ($latest_order_id);

$order = wc_get_order( $latest_order_id );
$order_data = $order->get_data();

print_r($order);
```

However, the data that I need to get is showing as this:

```
[data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 3767 [key] => billing_name [value] => David) )
```

I have searched the questions on the StackOverflow on this but unfortunately, I still can't access this. Does anyone have an idea of how I can get it? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function get_last_order_id(){
    global $wpdb;
    $statuses = "wc-completed";

    // Getting last Order ID (max value)
    $results = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT MAX(P.ID) ,PM.meta_value as firstname
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS P
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS PM
        ON P.ID = PM.post_id

         WHERE P.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
            AND P.post_status IN ('$statuses')
            AND PM.meta_key='_billing_first_name'" );
    return $results;
    }
    $latest_order_id = get_last_order_id(); // Last order ID
    $firstname = $latest_order_id->firstname;


    echo $firstname;
```